# image will be clicked automatically one time

Tags: javascript

I have an image in my site:

```
<img src = "bird.jpg" class="main_mark">
```

I want that while the user enters the site, this image will be clicked one time automatically.

How can I do that? Maybe I should define something in my JavaScript code?

Comment: Silly question, but _why_ does it need to be clicked?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this click ?

Comment: Great minds, or Fools - your choice... =)

Comment: because I have a youtube popup plugin and it's played after the user clicked the image twice (I don't know why). so I want that it will be clicked one time, and then: the user can click one time in order to play it. if the user clicks twice and closed the popup, he will have to click one time in order to popup the youtube. that's why I have to click only when the user presses the site.

$(".main_mark").click(function () {
        $(".main_mark").click(YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id', 'modal': true }));
 });

Comment: why don't you just drop one of the clicks then and use:  `$(".main_mark").click(YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id', 'modal': true }));`

Comment: ok, I tried it: $(document).ready(function() { $(".main_mark").click(YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id', 'modal': true }));
   $('.main_mark').trigger('click');
});
but the video doesn't popup although I pressed 5 times :/

Comment: Sorry, should have been: `$(".main_mark").click(function () { YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id', 'modal': true });});` - I think...

Comment: so my code should like so: $(".main_mark").click(function () { YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id', 'modal': true });});
    $('.main_mark').trigger('click');

if the answer is 'yes' so the popup isn't shown..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to trigger your popup with 1 click using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.main_mark').click(function(){
          YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id', 'modal': true });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery you can:

`$('.main_mark').trigger('click');`

or

`$('.main_mark').click();`

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work.. please see the comments of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jquery` for this like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.main_mark').click(function(){
          // Your code
     });
     $('.main_mark').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: @raad it was only for test purpose, I removed that.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work.. please see the comments of the topic.

Comment: Try this `$(document).on("click", ".main_mark", function(){YouTubePopup({ idAttribute: 'id', 'modal': true });});` in place of `$('.main_mark').click(function(){});`